# corpus search in Sketch Engine for particular correlative coordinators

Tags: corpora, research

Can someone teach me/show me how to search for either...or, neither...or/nor, whether...or and etc. in Sketch engine (in BAWE corpus particularly)? I have read basically every guide and watched a lot of youtube videos, but I still haven't stomped upon anything similar to what I need, or I'm just not smart enough, who knows... But anyway, save a poor student in need. 
I'm apologizing if this question, or whatever this is, is unrelatable for this page.